# How do I create a .onion site?

Tags: nginx, tor

I have a ubuntu linux and have been using this site: https://scottlinux.com/2013/10/11/how-to-create-a-tor-onion-site/ but I am getting confused on how to use this file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and from there everything else is a little confusing as well. If you know how to follow these instructions, please let me know.

Answer (score 11):

Its cool, I'll just answer my own question... Again.

Using this website helped me a lot more because it had step-by-step details that the one above was missing.

https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/security/290-hosting-tor-hidden-services-onions

Comment: This is old, but the only question I found. I followed this guide, but tor still isn't creating the "hidden_services" folder. Even tor's guide isn't helping me out here.

Comment: Modifying torrc doesn't work if the browser has been downloaded. Browser uses its own torrc that apparently can't be modified without crying "error". Any ideas (other than removing the browser)?

Comment: You waited for less than 5 hours to get a rarely asked question! Not cool

Comment: Use the official documentation from TOR: (use tor browser to access the link) http://xmrhfasfg5suueegrnc4gsgyi2tyclcy5oz7f5drnrodmdtob6t2ioyd.onion/onion-services/setup/

Answer (score -5):

The best way to create a .onion site would be through a Tor .onion homepage.Just follow the links there and you should create your own personal website quite easily.Or you could use a Tor Wiki to do so instead.